# How can get Summernote text to plain text from JSON data using Ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, summernote

I used Summernote text editor to input data. But now all data come with HTML tags.
How can I get this data into plain text?

[image: Here is my code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. My answer is given below:

[image: Here is the answer]